# Angular 5 app deployed to firebase won't load components

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, firebase-hosting

I was able to deploy an Angular 5 app to Firebase using `firebase init` and `firebase deploy`.

By default the main page is `index.html` from `public` directory.

I changed `firebase.json` from:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
```

to:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "src",
```

so that my `index.html` was shown.

And it is shown but the component inside it isn't loaded. I'm stuck with an empty page and `<app-root></app-root>` tag empty inside.

How can I configure firebase on my side so that it work as on my localhost?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my glasses or are those pieces of code exactly the same?

Comment: Could you please detail your question further?

Comment: My bad, it was a copy-paste mistake

Comment: But angular public is 'dist'

Comment: But dist is for production. Can't I use firebase for dev version?

Answer (score 0):

your project folder to instruct the Angular CLI to build a production-ready set of assets for your app in the dist folder:

```
ng build --prod
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase login
firebase init
```

Public directory: Type in `dist`, because this is where your production-ready Angular app assets are.

Configure as single-page app: Most of the time you’ll say `yes (y)` for this one.
Overwrite index.html: `No.`

[src](https://alligator.io/angular/deploying-angular-app-to-firebase/)